# User Defined Runtime Attributes on Launch Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, launch-screen

Why can't we add User Defined Runtime Attributes to a Launch Screen's subview? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The app is not yet loaded so the view hierarchy does not exist and the system can not call any custom view controller setup code you may have in the app (e.g. viewDidLoad). 
From the link.
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard/

I think because view hierarchy does not exist and to set runtime attributes the iOS uses KVO. And it is just a static view.
Alternative.
Have to use  static images with the feature you want.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when you provide runtime attributes in LaunchScreen.storyboard
please check right side , i have given corner radius, when i give cornerRadius here i Get "Launch screens may not contain user-defined runtime attributes. [12]" error. after removing attribute  resolve this issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As we don't have any class for launch screen.

You can do one thing,you can create a view controller with your desired Run time Attributes and show it immediately after launch screen.